# \distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3'

Tags: python, django

I've come across a github project which I am trying to install and run it but I've run into some problems( https://github.com/andrewschoen/django-cms-demo ). I've also put this up as an issue https://github.com/andrewschoen/django-cms-demo/issues/2 . The entire pip log is available there.

The problem appears to revolve around disutil, if I understand correctly:

```
f:\python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3'
 warnings.warn(msg)
 error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I'm just starting with python and django , having come from php. I'm trying to set this project up on a USB drive, and I'm working on win7.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts,

Bill

Comment: It's just a warning. The *error* is that you are trying to install on Windows something that needs a compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

You do not have a valid Visual C++ Installation in your System. [Visual C++ Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/visual-studio-express-products) is free and you can download and install it.

In Case, if Visual C++ is Installed but you are still facing the issue, check the following environment variables

VS100COMNTOOLS

VS110COMNTOOLS

To ascertain if they are set and locates to a valid Common7\Tools location

Comment: will the 2005 edition work or do you need the latest?